# Filtering paginated data with Winforms's Advanced DataGridView (or other control's suggestion?)

Tags: winforms, filter, datagridview, pagination

In my Winforms application I have a DataGridView control which data source is set to list of objects fetched from web api page. Data is paginated by 200 rows. I would like to create a filter to help user determine which rows are actually to be fetched. The thing is, I don't necessarily want to create custom filter control on my own, as there probably are ready controls (are there?). From open source options I've found brilliant Excel-like Advanced DataGridView by Zuby, which seems to be further developed by Davide Gironi. I managed to get filtering working using [this](https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview/issues/24) workaround and all is good except 1 issue. ADGV (and probably all other filters) seems to be designed to filter data ALREADY LOADED to the control, whereas I would like to use it to determine the rows to be fetched from Web Api. Don't get me wrong, I'm able to load chosen records - I'm sending filterstring to Web Api and I'm getting back proper rows. So it's more about creating appropriate filterstring. The thing is, the Excel-like filters let user choose only values already loaded to ADGV (please check the screenshot illustrating what I mean), whereas I'd like it to show all distinct values for a field.. As far as I understand my options are:

- somehow make ADGV show all distinct values: this would require having 2 separate data sources - one for ADGV (e.g. showing first 200 rows) and one for its "propositions" the user can choose from (I mean the control on the screen). I don't know ADGV too well and it's possible it can't be done.
- using other control (any propositions?)
- creating my own custom control (I'd like to avoid that)

[image: ADGV control allowing user to choose fitler values]

Comment: Download Syncfusion Community Edition and replace DataGridView with GridGroupingControl.

Comment: Thanks Josef. Installing Syncfusion just for that seems to me a bit of overkill.. I'd really prefer to avoid that, unless there's a control making all this simple. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I gave GridGrouping a look and it supports both pagination and filtering, but it looks like filter works only for on-page data, which doesn't work for me..

Comment: Could you explain what does it mean "on-page" data? I was using ADGV in some projects but than I moved to SyncFusion and Devexpress xtragrid which provides more easier things for paging, filtering, grouping, search grid... in just few lines of code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant "page size", the data that is already loaded in the grid. In my case there is 200 rows at start and I think filter will apply only to those, right?

Comment: Well I'm not sure. I didn't have that situation yet. You shoud try it. See this https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/gridgrouping/paging

Comment: _The filter can be applied to the records which are bound to the page._ I understand only bound records will be filtered, and bound are only those loaded to control. They later say it can be overcome if records are loaded to temporary table, but I'm not goin to load 1m records to table just to filter them.. I think I'm barking at wrong tree. It's not the filter I need but just a control to get query parameters from the user. If you have paginated grid, how do you get query parameters from user? I mean, for example, a situation when he would like to display records created in specified period

Comment: I solved this through SQL query... load only data from table by specific criteria and than display them in grid.